# .aux I couldn't open database file file.bib.bib

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, texmaker, auxiliary-files

whenever I am trying to compile its showing `.aux I couldn't open database file.bib.bib` 
I am using texmaker on windows 7. 
I already reinstalled MiKTeX and texmaker many times.

Comment: Have you some MWE? I suppose you wrote `\bibliography{foo.bib}` or something similar but I may be wrong

Comment: yeah I wrote \bibliography{bibfile.bib}{}

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `\bibliography{bibfile.bib}{}` but `\bibliography{bibfile}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{foo}

\bibliography{bibfile} 

\end{document}
```

During the compilation LaTeX try to add the `.bib` extension and so it goes wrong. since the file `bibfile.bib.bib` does not exist.

Comment: when I am using \bibligraphystyle(plain) this problem is coming 


This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: file.aux The style file: plain.bst Database file #1: file.bib A bad cross reference---entry "cheng" refers to entry "DBLP:conf/miccai/2013mlmi", which doesn't exist Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "DBLP:conf/miccai/2013mlmi" Warning--empty journal in mri Warning--empty year in mri (There was 1 error message)

Comment: @gauravkataria This is a problem within your database not answerable with the information currently provided. Please open a new question and add a suitable [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).